Praying Shemoneh Esrei with a big piece of spinach stuck between your teeth
Before saying the Amidah prayer, many men put on a hat and jacket.  They want to look good before they address Hashem, the King of Kings.
Imagine that you have a big piece of spinach stuck between your teeth.  And that, if you smile, the spinach is obviously visible to others.
Is it required to remove the piece of spinach before washing your hands and praying Shemoneh Esrei?
Possibly related

Brocha with food stuck in partial denture:  is it allowed?  This page discusses brachot on food, but doesn't discuss Shemoneh Esrei.
Can I pray Shacharis before brushing my teeth?


I think you'd have to wash your hands if you're touching your teeth.

@shmosel:  I've edited the question.
